# How to ignore white spaces in between tags, CSS, PHP

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs next to each other, with a space in between them, even though their margin is set to 0. I don't want the space to be there. The space is created by the white space in between the 2 div tags. I'm wondering if there is a way to ignore the white spaces in between tags while styling with css? Thanks.

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div></div> <div></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the font size of an ancestor to `0`...

```css
.parent {
    font-size: 0;
}

div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<span class="parent">
    <div></div> <div></div> 
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `display: inline-block;` which makes whitespace significant. Either get rid of the whitespace or get rid of inline display types.

You can also use floats.

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 0px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div></div> <div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in CSS, that I'm aware of, but you can remove the whitespace in the HTML by adding a comment between them.

```
<div>
</div><!--
--><div>
</div>
```

This works because everything inside the comment tag is ignored when the page is rendered.

Comment: What's the point of that? When you can just do this? <div></div><div></div>

Comment: More readable code if there's lots of content in the divs. No one wants to write all their html on one line.